# Almost unique constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, constraint

Is is possible to have a key in MySQL 5.7, which is unique for all values except one. Let's say -1 is a `not assigned` wildcard. Is it possible to have a table with the following structure

```
user | car | seat
1    | 1   | -1
2    | 1   | -1
3    | 1   |  2
```

That will allow

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (4, 1,  3)
INSERT INTO table VALUES (5, 1, -1)
```

and fail

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (4, 1, 2)
```

Same applies for updates.

Comment: *Let's say -1 is a not assigned wildcard.* `-1` - no. Use `NULL`.

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-to-create-a-conditional-index-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generated column as:

```
create table t
( user int not null primary key
, seat int not null
, gen int generated always as ( case when seat = -1 then -1*user 
                                                    else seat 
                                end ) stored
,    constraint xx unique (gen)
);

-- valid
insert into t (user, seat) values (1,-1), (2,-1), (3,2), (4,3), (5,-1);

-- invalid,  Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'xx'
insert into t (user, seat) values (6, 2);
```

Note that this assumes that users are not negative numbers.

EDIT: You may also consider normalizing your relation in two:

```
CREATE TABLE users
( user int not null primary key
, ...
);

CREATE TABLE user_seats
( user int not null references users (user)
, seat int not null primary key
-- if a user can only occupy one seat
, constraint ... unique (user)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can (ab)use `NULL` for this. Unique indexes allow multiple rows where the unique field is `NULL`. You just have to make sure you make the field nullable.

Note that this only applies to unique keys, not primary keys - primary keys cannot be nullable.